# Imploding to mysqli_fetch_array()

Tags: php

Im new to web development.
I need the array like following

*["Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"]*

I tried. But I failed.I connected the database. How can I make it?

**my array-code**

```
$count=0;
$sql="SELECT name FROM planet";
$sql_run=mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_run))
{
    $result[] = "'".implode("\'",$row)."'".",";
    echo $result[$count++];
}
```

By using above code, i couldn't get the result what I expected.

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: I don't at all understand why you write `"'".implode("\'",$row)."'".","`. Anyway, to get what you want, you must do `$result[] = '"' . $row['name'] . '"'` inside of the while().

Comment: I got like this, all are repeated.
'Mercury\'Mercury','Venus\'Venus','Earth\'Earth','Mars\'Mars','Jupiter\'Jupiter','Saturn\'Saturn','Uranus\'Uranus','Neptune\'Neptune',

but I need like this

_'Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth','Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune'_

Comment: thank you so much. its working. Really thanks. Problem is Im new to php@cFreed

Answer (score 1):

Each fetch returns one planet in associative array. To get array of rows, you have to do:

```
$list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_run)) {
     array_push($list, $row['name']);
}
var_dump($list);
```